# SQL Statements Not Executing

Tags: sql, windows, visual-c++, ms-access

I'm using Visual Studo 2010, Win7, C++ and Microsoft Access 2010 al 32 bit. I'm connecting with Direct ODBC.  The first SELECT Statement executes. The INSERT,SELECT,SELECT and UPDATE are not executing. I don't think it's the syntax of the SQL statement. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

const char* DAM = "Direct ODBC";

SQLCHAR szDSN[256] = 
"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ=C:\\FILEBLOCK\\Fileblocker.accdb;";

main()
{
    HENV    hEnv;
    HDBC    hDbc;

    SQLRETURN  rc, TOTAL, QUOTA;

    SQLSMALLINT  iConnStrLength2Ptr;
    SQLCHAR      szConnStrOut[255];

    SQLCHAR* query = (SQLCHAR*)"SELECT tblIP.[IPAddress], tblIP.[IPType], tblIP.[IPStatus], tblIP.[IPMax] FROM tblIP WHERE tblIP.[IPAddress]='173.201.216.2' AND tblIP.[IPType]=3 AND tblIP.[IPStatus]=1 AND tblIP.[IPMax]=0;";

/* Number of rows and columns in result set */
SQLINTEGER      rowCount = 0;
SQLSMALLINT     fieldCount = 0, column = 0;
HSTMT           hStmt;

/* Allocate an environment handle */
rc = SQLAllocEnv(&hEnv);

/* Allocate a connection handle */
rc = SQLAllocConnect(hEnv, &hDbc);

/* Connect to the 'Fileblocker.accdb' database */
rc = SQLDriverConnect(hDbc, NULL, szDSN,  _countof(szDSN), 
    szConnStrOut, 255, &iConnStrLength2Ptr, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);

if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc)) 
{
    printf("%s: Successfully connected to database. Data source name: \n  %s\n", 
       DAM, szConnStrOut);

    /* Prepare SQL query */
    rc = SQLAllocStmt(hDbc,&hStmt);
    rc = SQLPrepare(hStmt, query, SQL_NTS);

    /* Execute the query and create a record set */
    rc = SQLExecute(hStmt); 

    /* Loop through the rows in the result set */
        rc = SQLFetch(hStmt);
        while (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc)) 
        {
            rc = SQLFetch(hStmt);
            rowCount++;
        };

        printf("%s: Total Row Count: %d\n", DAM, rowCount);
        rc = SQLFreeStmt(hStmt, SQL_DROP);
        if (rowCount >= 1)
            {
            printf("PASS\n");
            SQLExecute ("INSERT INTO tblDownloads (tblDownloads.[DownloadIP] , tblDownloads.[DownloadCount]) VALUES('173.201.216.2', 1);");

            TOTAL = SQLFetch ("SELECT tblDownloads.[DownloadCount] WHERE tblDownloads.[DownloadIP] = '173.201.216.2';");
            QUOTA = SQLFetch ("SELECT tblIP.[IPQuota], WHERE tblIPID.[IPAddress] = '173.201.216.2';");

            if (TOTAL >= QUOTA)
                {
                SQLExecute ("UPDATE tblIP SET tblIP.[IPMax] WHERE tblIP.[IPAddress] = '173.201.216.2');");
                }
        else if (rowCount == 0)
            {
            printf("FAIL\n");
            rc = SQLFreeStmt(hStmt, SQL_DROP);
            }
        //system("pause");
    //}
}
else
{
    printf("%s: Couldn't connect to %s.\n", DAM, szDSN);
}

/* Disconnect and free up allocated handles */
SQLDisconnect(hDbc);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It **is** the SQL syntax.
The queries that are not executing are not syntactically correct, all of them:

**Query 1:**

```
INSERT INTO tblDownloads (tblDownloads.[DownloadIP] , tblDownloads.[DownloadCount]) VALUES('173.201.216.2', 1);
```

The column list after `INSERT INTO` must be without the table name as prefix.
Should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblDownloads (DownloadIP, DownloadCount) VALUES('173.201.216.2', 1);
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT tblDownloads.[DownloadCount] WHERE tblDownloads.[DownloadIP] = '173.201.216.2';
```

Missing `FROM` clause.
Should look like this:

```
SELECT tblDownloads.[DownloadCount] FROM tblDownloads WHERE tblDownloads.[DownloadIP] = '173.201.216.2';
```

**Query 3:**

```
SELECT tblIP.[IPQuota], WHERE tblIPID.[IPAddress] = '173.201.216.2';
```

Again, no `FROM`clause. Additionally, a comma too much and the table name in the `WHERE`clause is wrong.
Should look like this:

```
SELECT tblIP.[IPQuota] FROM tblIP WHERE tblIP.[IPAddress] = '173.201.216.2';
```

**Query 4:**

```
UPDATE tblIP SET tblIP.[IPMax] WHERE tblIP.[IPAddress] = '173.201.216.2');
```

One closing brace at the end without an opening brace.
Should look like this:

```
UPDATE tblIP SET tblIP.[IPMax] WHERE tblIP.[IPAddress] = '173.201.216.2';
```

Comment: Thank you Chris.  I tried all of them and still no go. The INSERT statement is still not inserting, etc.

Comment: @ME-dia: I know MS Access, but not C++. Maybe there are more issues in your code (other than the queries) but I'm the wrong guy to find them. I have one idea though: since you're using Visual Studio, do you have the database linked in your solution with "copy to output folder"? If yes, are you looking into the correct database to find your inserted record?

Comment: INSERT Now Working. Next is the Total Query. Here is what I get. Answer should be three. The first one returns 100, the second -1 and the third 100.     //SQLCHAR* query3 = (SQLCHAR*)"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblDownloads WHERE tblDownloads.[DownloadIP]= '173.201.216.2' AND tblDownloads.[DownloadCount]=1;";
 //SQLCHAR* query3 = (SQLCHAR*)"SELECT COUNT(*) tblDownloads.[DownloadCount] WHERE tblDownloads.[DownloadIP] = '173.201.216.2';";
 //SQLCHAR* query3 = (SQLCHAR*)"SELECT tblDownloads.[DownloadCount] FROM tblDownloads WHERE tblDownloads.[DownloadIP] = '173.201.216.2';";

Comment: The `COUNT` syntax is wrong...you have to specify a column to count, e.g. `SELECT COUNT(DownloadIP) FROM...`.

Comment: Actually Now I think Count() is wrong It should be Sum() since I want the total of DownloadCount in tblDownloads. Tried this, still no go.        SQLCHAR* query3 = (SQLCHAR*)"SELECT SUM(DownloadCount) AS DT FROM tblDownloads WHERE tblDownloads.[DownloadIP]='173.201.216.2'";

Comment: The query looks okay to me. For a start, did you try to run the queries directly in Access? If they don't run in your code but in Access, then something else in your code is wrong...